# Can I compare with a template string in an if statement in GitLab CI job rules?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I can do both

```
job-name:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "trigger"
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == $VAR
```

So, can I also do

```
job-name:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "trigger $VAR"
```

? I assume that it will be just interpreted as literal, i.e. without expansion of $VAR. I'm in the process of trial and error, but it's unsurprisingly unsuccessful because figuring out why GitLab jobs don't run is very very impossible.

Comment: I believe it works yes. You can try it by yourself, create two dummy vars and use them in the rules.

Comment: Unfortunately, no, I don't think expansion will work how you want in this case. But you may have an XY problem here. I suspect probably another way you can form your rule(s) to get the effect you want. If you could edit your question to explain what you're trying to accomplish, we may be able to help with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, variables cannot be expanded like this in `rules:if:`. This is documented in the [*where variables can be used*](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/where_variables_can_be_used.html) documentation. In relevant part it states `rules:if:` values cannot be expanded:

| Definition | Can be expanded? | Expansion place | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| [`rules:if`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#rulesif) | **no** | Not applicable | The variable must be in the form of $variable. Not supported are the following: - CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG variable. - [Persisted variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/where_variables_can_be_used.html#persisted-variables). |

This might be a bit confusing because of your ability to use *variable expressions* within a rule string literal... The rules engine always takes the `rules:if:` string literally and will interpolate [*variable expressions*](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#cicd-variable-expressions) within that literal. Like you have observed, the evaluation of *variable expressions* (in the form of `$variable` only) will allow variable substitution for entire operands, but not *within* string operands and not within patterns.
That is to say: `"trigger $VAR"` is simply a string literal, not a valid variable expression.

Comment: I was able to use another variable as you suggested. Thanks for the explanation and links.