# Gitlab-CI rule which compare variable to string of variables

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline

In gitlab-ci, I would like to trigger job only if `$CI_COMMIT_TAG` matches string which is made of two variables.

Example:

```
job1:
  variables:
    APP="my-app1"
    APP_VERSION="1.0.0"

  script:
    - some_cmd

  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG == "$APP-APP_VERSION"
```

- this pipeline should trigger job1 only if I commit a new specific tag "my-app1-1.0.0"

My point is that I use templates, and the rule should not be specific just for a one job, but for all jobs - every job has a unique values in variables ($APP and $APP_VERSION).

So the pipeline should trigger on `git tag` action and only specific job. But it does not work and I'm stuck...

**Is there any solution to evaluate those variables values?**

- I think that I can trigger all jobs and use if statement in a job's script block, but I would be much happier to evaluate it before the job run.

Comment: Excepted the typo (missing a dollar sign), your code should work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I compare with a template string in an if statement in GitLab CI job rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77687867/can-i-compare-with-a-template-string-in-an-if-statement-in-gitlab-ci-job-rules)

Comment: @sytech well, this says why it does not work, but I'm looking for a solution how to make it work.. i mean, what is the best alternative I have.. ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if one of the comments solved your issue, but you could also introduce an intermediate variable

```yaml
variables:
  APP_WITH_APPVERSION: $APP-$APP_VERSION
rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG == "$APP_WITH_APPVERSION"
```

Comment: It does not work, because the variable must be created in `job` level, and the rule is evaluated before the job run. I just used if statement in `before_script`, so job is stopped as soon as possible.

Comment: Interesting. Did not know so far that variable substitution is only done after rule evaluation, as raw values (both in job and in global scope) are available. It seems the `before_script` solution is the best way to go.